# React and Redux pattern

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm confused about the right way of using redux and react.
Lets say in my home `http://myapp/` I display a list of books, and I populate in my state an array `books[]` containing title and id. Each line in the home have a link to a page with book details, let's say `http://myapp/book/123`. When I load that route, I go to the server, fetch the data, create an action and reduce to have the book with id 123 filed with the details, so page can render properly. Is this the correct approach?
An if it is ok, whats if I use a link `http://myapp/book/123` directly? My app does not pass trough the home, so initial state is not initialized... I'm sure there is something wrong in my approach, but can't figure out.

Comment: Will you provide some code to go along with your verbal description?

Answer (score -1):

I found that Redux complicates things a lot. Since react introduced hooks I prefer to use hooks and simple context. You may find that your application does not need Redux at all. This may help: [replace redux react hooks context api](https://www.sitepoint.com/replace-redux-react-hooks-context-api/)